# Probability of summation of i.i.d. variables with a spherical joint distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, summation

I have a question regarding the probability of summed i.i.d. variables (log-returns) that have a joint spherical distribution. Obviously, the following statement holds:

$$
P(X_1 + ... + X_{10} < -0.1) = P(10^{1/2}X_1 < -0.1),
$$
where
$$
(X_1, ..., X_{10}) $$ has a spherical distribution.

I am wondering why the above does not evaluate to
$$
P(X_1 + ... + X_{10} < -0.1) = P(10^{1/2}X_1 + 10\mu< -0.1)
$$

Thank you,

Jam

Comment: Isn't it that $μ=E[X]=0$ so that actually both are the same?

Comment: Is that the case for all spherical distributions, or do you mean that it might be the case for this particular problem?

Comment: I saw [here](http://sfb649.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/fedc_homepage/xplore/tutorials/mvahtmlnode42.html) that the mean of every spherical is 0 since it can be seen as an extension of the standard normal. I think that this is it but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Yes, I have also checked that page. However, I have found spherical distributions that includes $\mu$, which have made me wonder...

Comment: Ok. Then perhaps someone else knows better.

Comment: But thank you !